# Can't assign multiple HTML elements in the .css() function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 4 divs `filter1`, `filter2`, `filter3`, `filter4` and I have an `anchor` tag inside of them and an `image`, I want to make it so that when you `hover` on a filter div, the `anchor` tag gets the other color, the only problem is that I cannot change the color via JavaScript, which is what I am trying to achieve.

I want to change the color of the anchor when I `hover` (or in JS `mouseOver`) any of the `filter` div.

The only problem is I cannot define multiple HTML tags in the .css function in JavaScript.

I am trying to achieve this:

```js
$(".filter1").mouseover(function () {
  $(".filter , li , a").css("color", "pink");
});
```

The only problem is, now every .filter function, every `li` tag and every `anchor` tag in my HTML documents get color pink when I hover over any of these.

What I have right now:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".filter1").mouseover(function () {
    $(".filter ").css("color", "pink");
  });
  $(".filter1").mouseout(function () {
    $(".filter li a").css("color", "#FFFF");
  });

  //also filter2, filter3, filter4 etc

});
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What's the reason of using JavaScript over CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the actual structure of a div, I'm going to think this should work.

You can do this with plain CSS:

```
.filter1:hover a{
  color:pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: Put the mouseover in the div and assign it a number

```
<div onmousover='colorChange(1)' onmouseout='colorRevert(1)' class='filter1'>
```

then in the jquery :

```
function colorChange(i){ 
     $(".filter" + i).css("color", "pink");
} 
function colorRevert(i) {
     $(".filter" + i + " li a").css("color", "#FFFF");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few observations.

First, **imvain** is correct: you do not need JS to do this, and honestly, you *should* do this using CSS.

```css
html { background: black; }

.filter1 li a {
  color: white;
}

.filter1 li a:hover {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Second, although it's the wrong approach, some advice on what was wrong with your code.

You attached your event handlers to the `.filter1` element, then changed the text colour on *every single link* on `mouseover`. Instead, consider listening for mouse events directly on the links; the specific element on which an event was triggered will be [bound to `this` in your event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/#stoppropagation).

You can refine this further by [using the `hover` shorthand](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) to set `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

```js
$('.filter1')
  .find('li a')
    .hover(
      function () {
        $(this).css('color', 'pink');
      },
      function () {
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
      }
    );
```

```css
html { background: black; }

.filter1 li a { color: white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filter1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.each()` method to aply the css to all childs.